# How to add gradient in React Native InputField theme primary color prop when a cursor is clicked in

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, gradient, linear-gradients

Suppose I have `TextInput` code like below:

```
<TextInput
 style={styles.firstNameInputField}
 mode="outlined"
 theme={{ colors: { text: '#4D4D4D' }, roundness: 5 }}
 value={nextData.first_name || ''}
 returnKeyType="next"
 onChangeText={(next) =>
  setNextData((prev) => ({ ...prev, first_name: next }))
 }
 outlineColor="#D7D7D7"
/>
```

and I want to use gradient in the primary colour props in below code.

```
theme={{ colors: { text: '#4D4D4D', primary: GRADIENT_HERE }, roundness: 5 }}
```

The `LinearGradientView` code is:

```
<LinearGradientView
                      colors={['#095FD8', '#8045E0']}
                      end={{
                        x: 0.01,
                        y: 0.28,
                      }}
                      start={{
                        x: 0.94077,
                        y: 0.03121,
                      }}
                      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                    />
```

How we can use it?

Comment: Are you putting TextInput inside of the gradient view? Where is your usage of LinearGradientView

Comment: No, I am not putting it inside TextInput. I did not figure out yet whether its possible or not. I find it difficult to set gradient in primary color thing.

Comment: Where does LinearGradientView come from? Please post a full reproducible example.

Comment: Its coming from `import { LinearGradient as LinearGradientView } from 'expo-linear-gradient';` I will try if I could post the entire code as its huge one and needs refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution for turning on and off a gradient, it to control the gradient colors in state to switch from `colors={[backgroundColor, backgroundColor]}` to the gradient.

Otherwise you can use a conditional wrapper to wrap your input in LinearGradientView only when it is selected.

```
export default function App() {
  const [on, setOn] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => setOn(!on)}
       style={styles.text}>
      <ConditionalWrap
      on={on}
      Wrapper={(children) => <LinearGradient
        colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#f92f6a']}
        style={styles.button}>
        {children}
        </LinearGradient>}
      >
      <Text>Sign in with Facebook</Text>
      </ConditionalWrap>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const ConditionalWrap = ({on, Wrapper, children}) => {
  if (!on) return children;
  return Wrapper(children);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Really appreciate it. But it did not work with my TextInput. :)

Comment: "didn't work" doesn't mean anything. What was the outcome? Did you check if wrapping the input in the gradient gives the desired result? Did you make the input transparent? Di d you check the DOM to make sure the conditional wrapper was implemented correctly?

Comment: The outcome was like having a thick border only on top. 
Yes, I did check that but it only applies some blue color from my theme. which I removed but still only thick border appeared on top of input. yes it was implemented correctly.